# How to select and join on a query with a table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I think this is just a syntax issue for me on Join but I am trying to Join a query to an existing table

```
select *
from
  (
    (select 'Source1' Source from Dual
     union select 'Source2' from Dual
     union select 'Source3' from Dual
     union select 'Source4' from Dual
     )
    cross join (
      select 'O' Status from Dual
      union select 'C' from Dual
     )
    cross join (
      SELECT
      TO_DATE('09/30/2013','mm/dd/yyyy') - 1 + LEVEL dt
      FROM dual
      CONNECT BY
      LEVEL <= ( TO_DATE('10/05/2013','mm/dd/yyyy')
           - TO_DATE('09/30/2013','mm/dd/yyyy')) + 1
     )
  ) as x
left join 
  (
    select myTable.mySource
    from myTable
  ) as y 
on y.err_sts_cd = x.Status
```

Comment: So your question is...? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just remove most of the grouping parens...

```
select *
from
    (select 'Source1' Source from Dual
     union select 'Source2' from Dual
     union select 'Source3' from Dual
     union select 'Source4' from Dual
     ) s
    cross join (
      select 'O' Status from Dual
      union select 'C' from Dual
     ) x
    cross join (
      SELECT
      TO_DATE('09/30/2013','mm/dd/yyyy') - 1 + LEVEL dt
      FROM dual
      CONNECT BY
      LEVEL <= ( TO_DATE('10/05/2013','mm/dd/yyyy')
           - TO_DATE('09/30/2013','mm/dd/yyyy')) + 1
     ) d
left join 
    myTable y
on y.err_sts_cd = x.Status
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no y.err_sts_cd

```
left join 
  (
    select myTable.mySource
    from myTable
  ) as y 
on y.err_sts_cd = x.Status
```

You need to either join using y.mySource or actually select err_sts_cd from myTable, aledgedly:

```
    select myTable.mySource, myTable.err_sts_cd
    from myTable
```